# AWS CLI2 -- Access via Federated SSO - Where to Obtain the 'SSO start URL'?

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cli

We have the AWS Console federated to our Shibboleth IdP (SAML).

Does AWS CLIv2 support using federated account to CLI access via SSO? If so -- where can I find the 'SSO start URL' listed in link below?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sso.html

Answer (score 2):

The other answers did not work for me. What I found to work was going to my organization's AWS landing page (`{my-organization}.awsapp.com/start#/`), and then there is a link under "AWS Account" called "Command line or programmatic access," which when clicked reveals instructions for setting up the CLI, including the SSO start url.

Answer (score -1):

This is labeled as the "User portal URL:" on the SSO Dashboard on AWS Console.

You must be logged in as the Organization's Master Account, and on the same region that SSO was enabled to see it.

Answer (score -1):

Get it from the AWS account where AWS SSO is configured. Example If you are using Control Tower, it will be the Control Tower account.
Service: AWS Single Sign On --> settings

There will be a field "User portal URL", that's it.